# Newbie graphviz edge direction issue

Tags: graph, graphviz

I have an **undirected** graph with the following schema:

```
graph G {
    A -- B;
    B -- C;
    C -- D;
    D -- A;
}
```

The graph is top to bottom as you see yourself. But I wanted to be in the form of a rectangle where A is top-left and D is bottom-right and I don't really have a clue how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got another solution without `neato` I guess that renders with `dot` properly.

```
graph G{
    {rank=same A B}
    {rank=same C D}

    A -- B;
    B -- C;
    D -- A;
    D -- C;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
graph G {
A [ 
label = A
pos = "0,0!" 
]
B [ 
label = B
pos = "5,0!"
]
C [ 
label = C
pos = "5,5!"
]
D [ 
label = D
pos = "0,5!"
]
A -- B;
B -- C;
C -- D;
D -- A;
}
```

and use `neato` to generate the image file. (it did not work with `dot` for me)

Comment: I have never heard of `neato`. Link?